# React how to detect route change method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have simply router in my React app and I want to have one component on every page and in that component I want to detect url is changing and change some classes depending on that route. I have problem that when I change url via NavLink my method is not being called I need to refresh to simulate that componentDidMount lifecycle method.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BannerTop />

        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/o-nas' strict exact component={AboutUs} />
          <Route path='/' strict exact component={Home} />
          <Redirect to='/' />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in this banner I want to change class

```
class BannerTop extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <section className={this.changeClass()} id='banner-top'>
        <div className='container'> Lorem </div>
      </section>
    );
  }

  changeClass = () => {
    console.log(this.props.location);
    return window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'home' : 'other';
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC for this.

Example:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class BannerTop extends Component {
  ...

  changeClass = () => {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;
    console.log(location);
    return location.pathname === '/' ? 'home' : 'other';
  };
}

export default withRouter(BannerTop);
```

Your `BannerTop` component is now automatically improved receiving all of the routing stuff you need.